# $d\omega \wedge \omega=0$ implies $d(f\omega)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to prove the following (**without the Frobenius Theorem**):

On $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $\omega$ is nowhere vanishing $1$-form such that $d\omega\wedge\omega=0$ then there exists (at least locally) $f$ a positive function such that $d(f\omega)=0$.

In fact, I am looking for an easier proof of the Frobenius theorem for distribution of hyperplanes. Indeed the proof I know are inductive, we start with distribution of lines, then inductively we arrive to distribution of hyperplanes.

My statement implies the Frobenius theorem for hyperplanes, so I wonder if we can prove it with as less as technology as possible?

Thanks for your help

Added: It is easy to prove that there exists a 1-form $\theta$ such that $d\omega =\theta \wedge \omega$, then
$d(f\omega)=(df+f\theta)\wedge \omega$, so the problem can be rephrased as, does there exisst $f$ and $g$ such that
$df+f\theta =g \omega$? I stuck here.

Comment: The problem here is that what you're trying to prove is not just implied by the Frobenius Theorem. It is *equivalent* to the Frobenius Theorem. So, if there were a simpler non-inductive proof known, we would all be teaching it, instead of the usual one.

More specifically, what you're trying to prove is the *last* step in the proof of the Frobenius Theorem. The condition $d\omega\wedge\omega = 0$ is equivalent to the condition that you have $n-1$ linearly independent vector fields whose Lie brackets lie in the span of the vector fields. This isn't easy to deal with directly.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419718/wanted-a-purely-algebraic-proof-of-the-frobenius-theorem-on-distributions), may be of interest, as it asks for a proof in a similar vein.

Comment: This is a deep theorem. You're not going to bypass it with some algebraic manipulation. Much as I am a devotee of differential forms, Frobenius needs a substantial proof.